# g++ Linker fails when using auto datatype

Tags: c++, g++, linker-errors, auto

I recently created a project which has a service to subscribe to via a class. You pass an unsigned long, a function pointer and your arguments to this. The arguments should be able to vary so I implemented it via the *auto* data type.

```
class TimerService {
public:
    TimerService();
    ~TimerService();

    void handler();

    void subscribe(uint32_t cycTm, void (*cbFunc) ());
    void subscribe(uint32_t cycTm, void (*cbFnc) (auto*), auto* arg1);
    void subscribe(uint32_t cycTm, void (*cbFnc) (auto*, auto*), auto* arg1, auto* arg2);

private:
    std::vector<TimerSubscriber*> subscribers;
};
```

Somewhere else in the code I then use this class.

```
void Test(int* i, int* j) {
    cout << *i " " << *j << endl;
}

timerService = new TimerService();

int var1 = 1;
int var2 = 2;

timerService->subscribe(5000, Test, &var1, &var2);
```

The compilation of the objects is working without any problems but when linking the objects the linker fails with "undefined reference to void TimerService::subscribe<int, int, int, int>(unsigned long, void (*)(int*, int*), int*, int*)".
What I did then is to change my "subscribe" function so that it takes *int* instead of *auto*. After that change it links without problem. How is it possible that the linker can't get along with the *auto* data type? Also the "subscribe" function which doesn't take any arguments is working without problems.

I'm using g++14 to compile with the "-fconcepts-ts" flag in order to enable the "auto" data type.

Comment: Which compiler version are you using? The following code gives compilation error in GCC 12.1 https://godbolt.org/z/888n6e7a1

Comment: I'm using GCC 10.3.1

Comment: When I use your link and adjust the compiler version to GCC 10.3 I actually get the exact error I'm having, too.

Comment: Using `auto` in a function declaration (for parameters), makes it a generic function. In this case, I would bet that the function has to be implemented in the header if it should be public (like templates). FYI: An explanation found in the Web: [Auto parameters generate templates](https://lesleylai.info/en/auto-parameters/#auto-parameters-generate-templates)

Comment: The question then becomes how I can fix it. Unfortunately the data types of the arguments vary and that's also why I chose the auto type. One thing I considered was using std::function and binding the arguments via std::bind and passing the result to the subscribe function

Comment: _Unfortunately the data types of the arguments vary_ How do you intend to call functions with varying signature? That doesn't work. But `std::function` sounds reasonable. Instead of fiddling with `std::bind`, you could as well use lambdas as adapters - easier to write, easier to read.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the idea of using lambdas as adapters?

Comment: If you want arguments that can be *anything* and don't rely on the function being a template, use ```std::any```

Comment: Unfortunately std::any is available only from g++17 onwards. I'm gonna stick to the std::function and std::bind variant. 
Thank you guys for the quick support.